# Mapping Generic API Response Using Codable or ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, codable, objectmapper

I am facing a challenge regarding mapping a generic api responses against a model class using codable or object mapper. Suppose I have these api responses against different apis.

```
{
  "code" : 0, 
  "http_response" : 200,
  "success" : true, 
  "data" : user
}

{
  "code" : 0, 
  "http_response" : 200,
  "success" : true, 
  "data" : locations
}

{
  "code" : 0, 
  "http_response" : 200,
  "success" : true, 
  "data" : countries
}
```

here user, locations and countries are separate codable/mapper classes.

I will have to construct a class like this

```
struct APIResponse : Codable {
    let success : Bool?
    let http_response : Int?
    let code : Int?
    let data : ??
}
```

How I will construct my base class to handle these responses using one class or I will have construct different classes just to change "data" type according to value?

Any kind of help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681385/swift-codable-multiple-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decoding method and `APIResponse` will look like this considering `user`, `countries`, `locations` are decodable,

```
struct APIResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var data: T?
    var code: Int
    var success: Bool
    var http_response: Int
}

func decode<T: Decodable>(data: Data, ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let res = try decoder.decode(APIResponse<T>.self, from: data)
        return res.data
    } catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Usage**

```
let data = Data() // From the network api 

//User
let user = decode(data, ofType: User.self)

// Countries
let countries = decode(data, ofType: [Country].self) 

// Locations
let locations = decode(data, ofType: [Location].self)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make generic constraint for you struct which says that `T` has to conform to `Decodable` and then use this type for specifing type of `data`

```
struct APIResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var code, httpResponse: Int
    var success: Bool
    var data: T
}

struct User: Decodable {
    var name: String
}
```

---

*note that I changed name of `httpResponse` parameter since I'm using `keyDecodingStrategy` which converts `http_response` to `httpResponse`*

---

Then while decoding specify type of `T`

**Single object**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let responses = try decoder.decode([APIResponse<User>].self, from: data)
    let user = responses[0].data /* data of type `User` of specific response */
} catch { print(error) }
```

**Array of objects**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let responses = try decoder.decode([APIResponse<[User]>].self, from: data)
    let users = responses[0].data /* data of type `[User]` of specific response */
} catch { print(error) }
```