# multiple types in Codable

Tags: swift, codable

I'm using an API which can either return a `Bool` or a `Int` for one value depending on the item. I'm not familiar with how to handle different types for one value in my `Codable` data. The rated key can either be an object or bool, just unsure how to handle this correctly without getting a `typeMismatch` error. This is my first time encountering this using an API.

```json
{"id":550,"favorite":false,"rated":{"value":9.0},"watchlist":false}
```

```json
{“id":405,"favorite":false,"rated":false,"watchlist":false}
```

```swift
struct AccountState: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let watchlist: Bool?
    let rated: Rated?
}

struct Rated : Codable {
    let value : Int? // <-- Bool or Int
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681385/swift-codable-multiple-types

Comment: I would simply decode false as nil. Btw it should be Double not Int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I definitely agree with @vadian. What you have is an optional rating. IMO this is a perfect scenario for using a propertyWrapper. This would allow you to use this Rated type with any model without having to manually implement a custom encoder/decoder to each model:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct RatedDouble: Codable {

    var wrappedValue: Double?
    init(wrappedValue: Double?) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }

    private struct Rated: Decodable {
        let value: Double
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            wrappedValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Rated.self).value
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let bool = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Bool.self)
            guard !bool else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Corrupted data"))
            }
            wrappedValue = nil
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        guard let double = wrappedValue else {
            try container.encode(false)
            return
        }
        try container.encode(["value": double])
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
struct AccountState: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let watchlist: Bool?
    @RatedDouble var rated: Double?
}
```

---

```
let json1 = #"{"id":550,"favorite":false,"rated":{"value":9.0},"watchlist":false}"#
let json2 = #"{"id":550,"favorite":false,"rated":false,"watchlist":false}"#
do {
    let accountState1 = try JSONDecoder().decode(AccountState.self, from: Data(json1.utf8))
    print(accountState1.rated ?? "nil")  // "9.0\n"
    let accountState2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(AccountState.self, from: Data(json2.utf8))
    print(accountState2.rated ?? "nil")  // "nil\n"
    let encoded1 = try JSONEncoder().encode(accountState1)
    print(String(data: encoded1, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")
    let encoded2 = try JSONEncoder().encode(accountState2)
    print(String(data: encoded2, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This would print:

> 9.0
> nil
> {"watchlist":false,"id":550,"favorite":false,"rated":{"value":9}}
> {"watchlist":false,"id":550,"favorite":false,"rated":false}

Comment: I'm just seeing how can my `Published` variable adapt to this change? I'm unsure of that aspect`@Published var state: AccountState = AccountState(id: 0, favorite: false, watchlist: false, rated: Rated(value: 0))`

Comment: @Cole  Just pass `rated: 0`. It is an optional Double. You can also pass `nil` (not rated). `@Published var state = AccountState(id: 0, favorite: false, watchlist: false, rated: 0)`

Comment: I tried that but getting `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'RatedDouble'`

Comment: I have `@RatedDouble var rated: Double?` in my `AccountState` declaration

Comment: @Cole Check my last edit

Comment: It's working and I don't get the type mismatch error! I can't thank you enough for the explanation, and help. It's definitely the most elegant solution. Accepting as answered :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to implement `init(from decoder`, declare `rated` as optional `Double` and decode a `Dictionary` or – if this fails – a `Bool` for key `rated`. In the former case `rated` is set to the Double value, in the latter case it's set to `nil`.

```
struct AccountState: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let favorite: Bool
    let watchlist: Bool
    let rated: Double?
     
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case id, favorite, watchlist, rated }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        favorite = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .favorite)
        watchlist = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .watchlist)
        if let ratedData = try? container.decode([String:Double].self, forKey: .rated),
           let key = ratedData.keys.first, key == "value"{
            rated = ratedData[key]
        } else {
            let _ = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .rated)
            rated = nil
        }
    }
}
```

The line to decode `Bool` in the `else` scope can even be omitted.

Comment: Is it at all possible to keep it `Codable` not `Decodable`?

Comment: Yes, then you have to implement also `encode(to:)` and specify how `rated` is supposed to be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

here is an easy way to do it (it's long, but easy to understand)

- **Step 1** - Create 2 types of Struct for your 2 kinds of format (from your sample, `rated` can be `Bool` or has `Double` as value)

```
// Data will convert to this when rate is bool
struct AccountStateRaw1: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let watchlist: Bool?
    let rated: Bool?
}

// Data will convert to this when rate has value
struct AccountStateRaw2: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let watchlist: Bool?
    let rated: Rated?

    struct Rated : Codable {
        let value : Double?
    }
}
```

- **Step 2** - Create your `AccountState` which can hold both kind of format

```
// You will use this in your app, and you need the data you get from API to convert to this
struct AccountState: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let watchlist: Bool?
    let ratedValue: Double?
    let isRated: Bool?
}
```

- **Step 3** - Make both of your structs of **Step 1** able to convert to struct of **Step 2**

```
protocol AccountStateConvertable {
    var toAccountState: AccountState { get }
}

extension AccountStateRaw1: AccountStateConvertable {
    var toAccountState: AccountState {
        AccountState(id: id, favorite: favorite, watchlist: watchlist, ratedValue: nil, isRated: rated)
    }
}

extension AccountStateRaw2: AccountStateConvertable {
    var toAccountState: AccountState {
        AccountState(id: id, favorite: favorite, watchlist: watchlist, ratedValue: rated?.value, isRated: nil)
    }
}
```

- **Final Step** - `data from API` --convert--> `structs of Steps 1` --convert--> `struct of Step 2`

```
func convert(data: Data) -> AccountState? {
    func decodeWith<T: Codable & AccountStateConvertable>(type: T.Type) -> AccountState? {
        let parsed: T? = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        return parsed?.toAccountState
    }
    return decodeWith(type: AccountStateRaw1.self) ?? decodeWith(type: AccountStateRaw2.self)
}
```